# How do I update SVG/HTML elements using the d3 each function with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, svg

I am having problems trying to update element attributes using d3 (v3.5) in TypeScript (v3.1). In JavaScript, I have code like the following.

```
function getAttr(d) {
 // modifies the "this" element with the following attribute
 d3.select(this).attr({
  id: d.id, cx: d.cx, cy: d.cy, r: d.r
 });
}

function drawCircles() {
 // update elements
 var svgCircles = d3.select('g#circles').selectAll('circle')
  .data(circles)
  .each(getAttr);
 // create elements
 svgCircles
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .each(getAttr);
 // delete elements
 svgCircles.exit().remove();
}
```

Note that in JavaScript, I pass a function to `each`, and that function somehow magically with `d3.select(this)` references the corresponding SVG/HTML element. This approach of using `this` cannot be done in TypeScript as `this` will **not** be a reference to the corresponding SVG/HTML element.

There are a few examples online that get close to addressing this problem, but they fall short. This [blog post](https://hstefanski.wordpress.com/2015/10/25/responding-to-d3-events-in-typescript/) talks about `this` problem in the context of handling event. To get a reference to the SVG/HTML element, the author uses `d3.event.currentTarget` (such property is not available and/or defined in the d3 version I am using). This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154312/d3-update-example-in-typescript-scoping-issue) would have addressed my problem except the update does not involve `each`.

Any ideas on how to modify SVG/HTML elements corresponding to data elements via `each`?

As a workaround, without using `each` as I realize it introduces a lot of problems, I'm following this [JavaScript update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/lmatteis/0a11aa639095e888a01f7972056d38c9) and it plays well with TypeScript. I like it in that it works, but not so much since I have to line-by-line update the attributes.

```
drawCircles(): void {
 // data join
 const svgCircles = d3.select('g#circles')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(circles);
 // create
 svgCircles.enter().append('circle');
 // create + update 
 svgCircles.attr('id', (datum) => datum.id);
 svgCircles.attr('cx', (datum) => datum.cx);
 svgCircles.attr('cy', (datum) => datum.cy);
 svgCircles.attr('r', (datum) => datum.r);
 // delete
 svgCircles.exit().remove();
}
```

Comment: If all you are trying to do is change the attributes, why aren't you just using the `attr()` function?

Comment: If you really wanted to make it one line, just write your own function.

Comment: What error are you seeing?  The way you have it coded, using a function (not fat arrow) with `.each` should pass in the element as this.  Usually people ask the [opposite question to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575599/16363).